# gulp-useref: selective transformStream to prune bootstrap produces invalid output files

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, minify, gulp-useref

I use `gulp-useref` to concatenate and minify my script assets. Since my project incorporates some `bootstrap` styles I would like to prune all unnecessary parts of it. For this purpose I've integrated the `gulp-purifycss` plugin. I now tried to use `gulp-useref`'s `transformStream` capabilities to selectively purify only `bootstrap.css`, which results in invalid output files for both my minified javascript and CSS. For instance, the produced javascript file also contains all of `bootstrap.css` and the CSS file contains only about two lines of my own CSS.

Here is my gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var htmlminOpts = {
  collapseWhitespace: true,
  removeComments: true,
  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
  removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
  minifyJS: true,
  minifyCSS: true
};
var cssminOpts = {
  keepSpecialComments: 0
};

// ...

gulp.task('scripts:public', function() {
  return gulp.src('client/public/index.html')
    .pipe($.useref({
      searchPath: ['client/public', './']
    }, require('lazypipe')().pipe($.if, function(file) {
      return file.path.indexOf('bootstrap.css') > -1;
    }, $.purifycss(['client/public/**/*.html']))))
    .pipe($.if('**/bower_components/**/*.js', $.fixmyjs()))
    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify().on('error', $.util.log)))
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.htmlmin(htmlminOpts)))
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.cssmin(cssminOpts)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/client/public'));
});
```

Probably I'm using the `transformStream` in a wrong way, however the documentation is pretty meager in this regard, as it only tells me
`Transform assets before concat.`, which would be exaclty what I want: Transform `bootstrap.css` via `purifycss` before it gets concatenated with my own CSS.

Thank you in advance for any hints into the right direction!

Comment: You should post your complete gulpfile.js and the package.json as well.

Comment: I don't think the complete gulpfile.js is necessary but I will edit in the code referenced in the task. My gulpfile is 300+ lines, mostly irrelevant to the problem. Also I don't see how my `package.json` can be of use here. It obviously contains dependencies to all the packages used by my node application and gulp.